# ¿Como mandar imprimir con js sin que salga el cuadro de dialogo de la impresora?

Tags: javascript, impresion

Tengo un código de php que genera un listado de "ordenes" a imprimir y que se pueden seleccionar con unos checkbox, necesito que las ordenes que se seleccionen para imprimir quedan marcadas como "impresas" pero solamente hasta que realmente se hayan mandado realmente a imprimir, se que existe el comando window.print() pero este comando NO ME SIRVE por que lo que hace es abrir el cuadro de dialogo de impresión y eso no significa que realmente el usuario haya mandado imprimir, entonces lo que necesito es un comando en js que mande ejecutar el archivo php que se encargará de registrar las ordenes impresas pero hasta que realmente se haya ejecutado la impresión.

Me encontré esté código en la web pero no funciona, me marca :pruebadirecto.html:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: POST is not defined.  ¿Alguna orientación?

```js
var data = new FormData();
data.append(""printer"", ""[printer name]"");
data.append(""url"", ""[url with a document to print]"");           //if url not send path

POST('http://localhost:8888/, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
}, data);
```

Comment: Respuesta simple: *no puedes*. Javascript no tiene acceso (por razones obvias de seguridad) a los recursos del sistema operativo donde se ejecuta el navegador. Saludos

Comment: No quiero que tenga acceso, solo quiero que se disparé una función cuando se manda a imprimir

Comment: Al no tener acceso a los recursos no puedes detectar si verdaderamente se imprimió el archivo, solo te toca confiar en que la persona le dio a imprimir

Comment: Tal vez podrías hacer algo como enviar los documentos seleccionados como PDF para su descarga / impresión, en ese momento (al enviar los documentos desde el Servidor al Cliente) los podrías marcar como "impresos" o "entregados". No hay forma que el Servidor se entere si se han impreso realmente o no. Si necesitas el comportamiento de una app de escritorio del lado cliente, podrías plantearte usar [ElectronJS](https://www.electronjs.org/). Saludos

Comment: para que es el ElectronJS ?